# Can Rails' "Validates Uniqueness" override an existing record with new one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three time slots per day, and a bunch of candidate posts for publication. I'm making a little tool that lets us arrange candidates into slots for the next few weeks to see what the schedule might look like. We often have to rearrange, dragging one candidate from its current time slot to another one.

I have a model called `PublishTime` that pairs a `candidate_id` and a `datetime`.  I know that I can set up the model to validate the uniqueness of both `candidate_id` and `datetime`, which would preserve uniqueness by preventing the creation of a new record that has an existing `candidate_id` or an existing `datetime`.

What I'd like to do instead is to preserve the uniqueness by deleting any existing records that have the `candidate_id` or `datetime` of the new record I'm creating. I'd like the new record to override any existing records. Is there a built-in way to do this?

Comment: You might want to provide more detail - I think there might be a better way to accomplish your higher-level goals.

Comment: Added a bit of detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `find_or_initialize_by` which is an `upsert` operation. If the record is new you insert it. If one already exists based on your requirements, you update it.

For example:

```
scope = params.slice(:candidate_id, :datetime)

publish_time = PublishTime.find_or_initialize_by(scope) do |new_publish_time|
  # optional block if you need to do something with a new model   
  # do something with `new_publish_time`
end

publish_time.assign_attributes(params)
publish_time.save!
```